# Using JavaScript to control a WebPage Reload

Tags: javascript, html, automation, tampermonkey

I have this script in Tampermonkey which auto-reloads a web-page periodically.

```html
(function() {
    'use strict';
setTimeout(function(){
   window.location.reload(1);
}, 180000);
})();
```

But is there any way whereby this condition can be ignored if it detects my mouse pointer on that page. Because I don't want to end up reloading the page in the middle of a task.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
var reloadTimeout = setTimeout(function(){
    window.location.reload(1)
}, 180000)

document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(){
    clearTimeout(reloadTimeout)
})
```

Effectively, this code is assigning the timeout associated with reloading the page to a variable, which you can then use to clear the timeout when you detect a `mousemove` event, which is what I assume you mean by "detecting your mouse pointer."

Comment: With the above script what happens is, the page doesn't reload until I navigate back to the page. I set my script and have other tabs open and then the page reloads the moment I come back to the tab where I have configured this script. I was hoping the page continues to reload in the background and when it detects "mousemove" or "mousepointer" the script would timeout then.